# Passing Wordpress objects from parent to popup child using PHP SESSION

Tags: php, wordpress, session, popup, parent-child

I am passing an array of WP objects (ie, WP_User) from Wordpress site to a popup window using $_SESSION variable.

When popup is open, I `var_dump($_SESSION['variable']['WP_Users'])` and everything looks good.

However, when I am trying to access `$_SESSION['variable']['WP_users'][0]->data->parameter`, all values are NULL.

Aside from that, error_log says:

> "main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an **incomplete object**. Please ensure that the class definition "WP_User" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  in /*ABSPATH*/popup_template.php line 52"

As I understand, my popup has no definitions of WP classes, such as WP_User etc., therefore I am unable to manipulate WP objects.

Any ideas on how to tackle this? (keep in mind I am not using (un)serialize() at all)

Answer (score 0):

So solution was actually pretty straightforward: I had to do what `error_log` asked.

In parent window I had to serialize array of Wordpress objects before shoving them into the SESSION var like so:

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = serialize( $array_of_WP_objects );
```

To my popup template I had to add definition of `WP_User` from wp_includes folder, and then unserialize my array back to `$array_of_WP_objects` like so

```
require_once( '../../../../wp-includes/class-wp-user.php' );
$array_of_WP_objects = unserialize( $_SESSION['variable'] );
```

Worked like a charm.